# PHP echo php but replace any space

Tags: php

Hi I am echoing out a field name which is going to be part of a url. However the name itself has uppercase lettyers in it so I have made them all lower on the echo. There is however a space between words. Is there a way I can also replace any spaces here with a hiphen on the echo?

```
<?php echo strtolower($row["myfield"]); ?>
```

Comment: Have you heard of `str_replace`? Is there any problem in using it?

Comment: try ```<?php echo str_replace(' ','-', strtolower($row["myfield"])); ?>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the spaces with another string:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row["myfield"])); ?>
```

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [,
>   int &$count ] )

Documentation:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Why should the spaces get replaced by nothing if the OP asks for a replacement with hyphens?

Comment: Oh, misread the question.. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$row["myfield"]));
```

Based on the comments below.
This code does two operation, first takes "myfield" and replatces the white space with hyphens, it does that using the str_replace() function of php. This function returns a string that is then used with conjuction with strtolower to make all letters lower.

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain how the code works and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For just spaces, use str_replace:

```
   <?php echo str_replace(' ', '',strtolower($row["myfield"])); ?>
```

For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
  <?php echo  preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($row["myfield"])); ?>
```